# Join to return multiple columns and using group by Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to build this Entity Framework query to return this four columns:

`Cidade = a.Nome, Estado = b.Uf, TemperaturaMinima = d.TemperaturaMinima, TemperaturaMaxima = d.TemperaturaMaxima`

But I don't want the Cidade column repeat. So I don't know how to use Group by just in the Cidade column and return all this four columns.

Could you help me?

```
`var cidadesMaisFrias = (from a in _contexto.Cidades
                                join b in _contexto.Estados
                                on a.EstadoId equals b.Id
                                join d in _contexto.PrevisaoClimas
                                on a.Id equals d.CidadeId
                                where d.DataPrevisao >= DateTime.Parse("23/11/2021") &&
                                d.DataPrevisao <= DateTime.Parse("29/11/2021")
                                orderby d.TemperaturaMinima ascending

                                select new
                                {
                                    Cidade = a.Nome,
                                    Estado = b.Uf,
                                    TemperaturaMinima = d.TemperaturaMinima,
                                    TemperaturaMaxima = d.TemperaturaMaxima
                                }).Take(3).ToList();`
```

Comment: What do you mean you do not want `Cidade` repeat? What do you mean by `how to use Group by just in the Cidade column`?

Comment: Show your model. Probably you have bad join which duplicates records.

Answer (score 0):

Hi :) I hope I understood your requirement correctly - you want the find 3 coldest cities you have in the DB, right? Here is my take. I basically just changed join to group join, so there is one entry for each city instead of duplicate entries. Also I moved the sorting to the end.

```cs
    var minDate = DateTime.Parse("23/11/2021");
    var maxDate = DateTime.Parse("29/11/2021");
    var toTake = 3;
        
    var cidadesMaisFrias = _contexto.Cidades.Where(c => true) // select all cities, no filter
            .GroupJoin(_contexto.Estados,
                c => c.EstadoId,
                e => e.Id,
                (c, e) => new { Citade = c, Estado = e } // here you get Citade with list of it's Estados (shoudl be one Estado)
                )
            .GroupJoin(_contexto.PrevisaoClimas,
                ce => ce.Citade.Id,
                pc => pc.CidadeId,
                (ce, pc) =>
                    new
                    {
                        Citade = ce.Citade.Nome,
                        Estados = ce.Estado.First().Uf,
                        TemperaturaMinima = pc.Where(x=>  x.DataPrevisao >= minDate && x.DataPrevisao <= maxDate).Min(x=>x.TemperaturaMinima), // first filter forecasts by date, then get smallest temperature
                        TemperaturaMaxima = pc.Where(x=>  x.DataPrevisao >= minDate && x.DataPrevisao <= maxDate).Max(x=>x.TemperaturaMaxima) // first filter forecasts by date, then get highest temperature
                    }
                )
            .OrderBy(x=>x.TemperaturaMinima) // sort by coldest
            .Take(toTake) // take 3 coldest 
            .ToList();
```